# Solr 6: Joining Documents should give both documents fields

Tags: mysql, solr

I am storing documents in Solr like below, where these two documents belong to user_id 9. And get documents by searching on title and description which I than again filter on shortest distance within radius of 10 km which is working fine. But sometimes user change their location which means I have to update all documents of that user_id, good for small documents number but for more than 500 documents, it's bad.

```
{
        "id":"11",
        "title":"post title",
        "description":"Post description.",
        "created_at":"2017-12-30T13:56:22Z",
        "updated_at":"2017-12-30T13:59:28Z",
        "user_id":9,
        "name":"SHOP Name",
        "company_name":"Company Name",
        "latitude":26.2915005,
        "longitude":50.1811244
},

{
        "id":"12",
        "title":"post title2",
        "description":"Post description2.",
        "created_at":"2017-12-30T13:56:22Z",
        "updated_at":"2017-12-30T13:59:28Z",
        "user_id":9,
        "name":"SHOP Name",
        "company_name":"Company Name",
        "latitude":26.2915005,
        "longitude":50.1811244
}
```

One solution I think of is to store separate users & posts document and make join queries but according to Solr join you can't get all fields ([Reference link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join)).

> For people who are used to SQL, it's important to note that Joins in
> Solr are not really equivalent to SQL Joins because no information
> about the table being joined "from" is carried forward into the final
> result. A more appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".

The second I am thinking of is to create separate user data on Mysql and update location or other user information on Mysql side because of this I don't have to update documents on Solr. When someone search, I first get all matched posts from Solr, after that I'll filter shortest distance of 10 km radius manually by getting user data from mysql and return results. But this will make searching slower.

If somebody have any suggestions please tell me so that I can solve this problem. I think better solution is to create separate user document on Solr and join somehow. Is there anything in Solr which I am missing, any functionality?

Comment: so when you say user updates their location you mean lang and lat will get updated?

Comment: Yes, it will updates all posts/documents latitude and longitude of that user id